# Make sure all SQS messages received while set ReservedConcurrentExecutions more than 0

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, aws-lambda, concurrency, amazon-sqs

I have a service that uses both Lambda function and SQS. One Lambda function sends messages via SQS to trigger another function. Because the receiver function is going to call an API which blocks frequent visits (status code = 403), I need to reserve the concurrent executions to avoid that. However, that also results in the message not being consumed and gone missed in the queue. So is there another way to make sure no messages go missed while there's maximum concurrency?

Function properties:

```
VideoRouter:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      FunctionName: !Sub router-${Environment}
      Handler: lambda_function.lambda_handler
      Runtime: python3.7
      CodeUri: router/
      Description: something
      MemorySize: 256
      Timeout: 900
      ReservedConcurrentExecutions : 5
      Role:
        Fn::GetAtt:
        - LambdaRole
        - Arn
      Environment:
        Variables:
          LOGGING_LEVEL: INFO
          APP_NAME: APPS
          APP_ENV: !Ref Environment
          BUCKET: !Sub my-bucket-${Environment}
          PITCH_AI_DB: !Sub db-${Environment}
          PROPLAY_CREDENTIALS: /credentials/
      Tags:
        env:
          Ref: Environment
        service: my-service
        function_name: !Sub my-router-${Environment}
      Events:
        MySQSEvent:
          Type: SQS
          Properties:
            Queue: !GetAtt QueueA.Arn
            BatchSize: 1
```

Queue Properties:

```
RouterQueue:
    Type: AWS::SQS::Queue
    Properties:
      QueueName: !Sub router-queue-${Environment}
      VisibilityTimeout: 900
      RedrivePolicy:
        deadLetterTargetArn: 
          Fn::GetAtt: RouterDeadLetterQueue.Arn
        maxReceiveCount: 10
  RouterDeadLetterQueue: 
    Type: AWS::SQS::Queue
    Properties:
      QueueName: !Sub router-dead-letter-queue-${Environment}
      MessageRetentionPeriod: 1209600
```

Comment: In your Lambda function's code (the one receiving the SQS messages) are you checking if more than one message is in the `event` object?

Comment: Well, I used for-loop to traverse everything so there wouldn't be missing

Comment: Yes that's what I meant by checking for more than 1 message.

Comment: Are you saying that messages are not appearing, or are you saying that messages are going to the Dead Letter Queue? If they are going missing, then **configure the Trigger that calls the 2nd Lambda function from SQS to have a Batch Size of 1**. This will ensure that only a single message is passed to the Lambda function because, as queried by @MarkB, it might be receiving multiple messages that your code is ignoring.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong: you are saying we can configure the lambda function's batch size?